# How to get sum for different entry in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table in mysql like

```
| service_code | charges | caller_number | duration | minutes |
+--------------+---------+---------------+----------+---------+
|           10 |      15 | 8281490235    | 00:00:00 |  1.0000 |
|           11 |      12 | 9961621709    | 00:00:00 |  0.0000 |
|           10 |      15 | 8281490235    | 01:00:44 | 60.7333 |
|           11 |       2 | 9744944316    | 01:00:44 | 60.7333 |
+--------------+---------+---------------+----------+---------+
```

from this table I want to get charges*minutes for each separate caller_number.
I have done like this

```
SELECT sum(charges*minutes) as cost from t8_m4_bill groupby caller_number
```

but I am not getting expected output. Please help?

Comment: And what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT caller_number,sum(charges*minutes) as cost 
from t8_m4_bill 
group by caller_number
order by caller_number
```

Comment: ok thanks, if i want only results having service_code starts with 'o' `SELECT sum(charges*minutes) as cost,caller_number ,service_code  from t8_m4_bill group by caller_number having service_code LIKE '0%';` but it returns one row only even i have more than one??

Comment: Either only return 1 column (the sum), or multiple with every column not an aggregate fcn in the group by

Comment: @NishamMahsin it is because your service_code type might be INT, change to VARCHAR and then try.

Comment: SELECT sum(charges*minutes) as cost,caller_number ,service_code from t8_m4_bill group by caller_number, service_code where service_code LIKE '0%';